# Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '([AnyObject]) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project code as below, I wish it can get urls from func getUrls(), but Xcode returns error message like title says.

I have search and try some solution to fix it, but all not works. Should I write it with another way, or just fix this error ? Is the declaration for arrUrls was wrong, or somewhere need to make correction?

p.s. If you answer me by a comment, remember to teach me how to make an "Answered mark" for your answer.:) Thank you.

```
var arrUrls = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


getUrls(url: url, completion: arrUrls) // Error Message: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '([AnyObject]) -> Void'

...do something with array 'arrUrl'....but can't, because of the bug!

}



func getUrls(url : URL  ,completion: @escaping (([AnyObject]) -> Void)) {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {

                if let subjects = jsonResult["subjects"] as? [AnyObject]? {

                    for subject in subjects! {
                        if let content = subject["content"] as? [String : AnyObject] {

                            let s = String(describing: content["url"]!)
                            arrUrls.append(s)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            completion(arrUrls as [AnyObject])
        }catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Remove the line, start writing it again, and let XCode autocomplete help you.

Comment: Unrelated but in Swift 3+ the unspecified type is `Any`, not `AnyObject` and don't misuse `String(describing:)`

Comment: vadian: It still shows "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '([Any]) -> Void'", after I replace AnyObject wit Any.......

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking into using Codable to avoid JSON parsing.: https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4

Comment: I know,  hence I wrote *unrelated*

Comment: Larme: After I try it, I ......still don't know how to fix. Am I declare arrUrls type wrong? Because getUrls() always needs a ([AnyObject]) parameter.....?

Comment: Did you copy/paste from elsewhere the line `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in`? Because it's exactly the same behavior: a closure parameter.

Comment: vadian: Still thank you!!

Comment: Larme: Yes. You are right, should I modify which line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call like this

```
getUrls(url: url) { (arr) in


}
```

if you edit the array inside the function then no need to return a completion value

```
func getUrls(url : URL  ,completion: @escaping (() -> Void))
```

with

```
getUrls(url: url) {  

  // refresh ui here

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
   if firstItem = self.arrUrls.first , let url = URL(string:firstItem) {
      webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
   }
 }
```

---

change code to this

```
func getUrls(url : URL  ,completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String : Any] {

                if let subjects = jsonResult["subjects"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                    for subject in subjects {

                        if let content = subject["content"] as? [String : Any] {

                           if let s = content["url"] as? String
                           {
                              self.arrUrls.append(s)
                           }
                        }
                    }

                    completion()

                }
            }

        }catch {

            completion()
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But webview should change setting in main thread only...(Xcode says), so I only can wait URLSession.shared.dataTask finish it's work, and save all url to array, and then change web view setting.....

Comment: yes when you call that function embed any ui content inside **DispatchQueue.main.async** as completion is inside a background thread

Comment: This seems to be work, but.. where I set web view url? Because webview only can change setting in main thread..., this is a problem.

Comment: After I change the code, the error message change to "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '() -> Void'"........ It's seems always the type not match....

Comment: @Simon you have an array of urls the webview can load 1 at a time , i updated answer with loading first url see edit..............

Comment: Ok, I edited my code, app and simulator run successfully, but its shows "...must be used from main thread only" error message after app runs, maybe command in DispatchQueue.main.async still not in main thread.